# VirtualBox stuck on "Starting Virtual Machine"

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I just got a new work laptop but I am having a lot of difficulty getting VirtualBox to run on it. It basically fails to start the virtual machine when I try boot it and remains stuck on "Starting Virtual Machine"

Looking at `dmesg` is proving very cryptic for me:

```
$ dmesg | grep vbox
[Tue Feb  3 16:53:49 2015] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[Tue Feb  3 16:53:49 2015] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores.
[Tue Feb  3 16:53:49 2015] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0xcf offMax=0xff9
[Tue Feb  3 16:53:49 2015] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[Tue Feb  3 16:53:49 2015] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.20 (interface 0x001a0008).
[Tue Feb  3 16:53:49 2015] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[Tue Feb  3 17:08:22 2015] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores.
[Tue Feb  3 17:08:22 2015] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0xd8 offMax=0x1d31
[Tue Feb  3 17:08:22 2015] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[Tue Feb  3 17:08:22 2015] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0008).
[Tue Feb  3 17:08:22 2015] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:18 2015] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores.
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:18 2015] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0xdb offMax=0x2436
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:18 2015] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:18 2015] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0008).
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:18 2015] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:22 2015] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores.
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:22 2015] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0xd8 offMax=0xc60
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:22 2015] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:22 2015] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0008).
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:22 2015] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:46 2015] Modules linked in: vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) ctr ccm pci_stub uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev arc4 media intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel cdc_mbim cdc_wdm kvm cdc_ncm cdc_acm usbnet mii btusb iwlmvm mac80211 joydev snd_hda_codec_realtek serio_raw snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic iwlwifi lpc_ich snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec rfcomm bnep snd_hwdep cfg80211 snd_seq_midi bluetooth snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm 6lowpan_iphc mei_me mei shpchp snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer nvram snd mac_hid soundcore parport_pc ppdev nls_iso8859_1 lp parport uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:46 2015]  i915 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit psmouse drm_kms_helper ahci e1000e libahci drm ptp pps_core wmi video [last unloaded: vboxdrv]
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:46 2015]  [<ffffffffc08d3b97>] ? supdrvIOCtl+0x1437/0x2d30 [vboxdrv]
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:46 2015]  [<ffffffffc08dbf99>] ? rtR0MemAllocEx+0x1a9/0x290 [vboxdrv]
[Tue Feb  3 17:09:46 2015]  [<ffffffffc08cd544>] ? VBoxDrvLinuxIOCtl_4_3_18+0x124/0x230 [vboxdrv]
```

I have installed virtualbox on many different work laptops (including the same model laptop from a previous generation) and never had any issues.

I have enabled virtualization from setup so that is not the issue. I have also rebuilt virtualbox several times in case it failed to compile against the current kernel correctly.

Is there something from `dmesg` that points to a fundamental flaw or something that I am completely overlooking?

Any help would be appreciated as it's prevented me from getting any work done which is extremely frustrating.

- **VirtualBox**: 4.3.18
- **Laptop Model**: Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd Generation)
- **Ubuntu Version**: 14.10
- `uname -a`:

  ```
    Linux Arturis 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a missing feature in VirtualBox and will be fixed in future releases. Please add `nosmap` to the kernel parameters of the host kernel. To follow this problem, see  [VirtualBox ticket 13820](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13820).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Please check if the VBoxSVC service is still running when you try to start the VM with VBox 4.3.18.

Make sure that you have the use I/O APIC, and the Use host I/O cache options are checked.

[image]

[image]

Also you may want to upgrade to 4.3.20, since it have a lot of fixes over 4.3.18.

Comment: Use Host I/O Cache do it for me

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shot-in-the-dark, but possibly try turning off IOMMU in GRUB?

In `/etc/default/grub`, change the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=off"
```

Found on [this VirtualBox forums topic](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=47963)

Comment: It's very unlikely to be the cause but I'll give it a shot on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: The marked answer is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I landed here while experiencing a similar problem.

In my case, I had these lines in journal logs when the VM got stuck:

```
Jun 15 10:59:42 fedora-desktop kernel: SUPR0GipMap: fGetGipCpu=0x1b
Jun 15 10:59:43 fedora-desktop gnome-shell[10050]: syntax error: line 1 of stdin
Jun 15 10:59:43 fedora-desktop gnome-shell[10050]: Errors encountered in stdin; not compiled.
Jun 15 10:59:43 fedora-desktop kernel: traps: Missing ENDBR: 0xffffab45219b24a0
Jun 15 10:59:43 fedora-desktop kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 15 10:59:43 fedora-desktop kernel: kernel BUG at arch/x86/kernel/traps.c:255!
Jun 15 10:59:43 fedora-desktop kernel: invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
```

This is due to a bug being tracked in https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/21435

The solution in this case is to add a `ibt=off` arg to the kernel boot args, which disables the "indirect branch tracking" feature of some Intel CPUs.

Note that the "indirect branch tracking" is a security feature from Intel, so you may want to take a better look before disabling it: https://lwn.net/Articles/889475/

But this was the only way I could run VMs again with Virtualbox on Fedora 38 (On Ubuntu the same solution should work).

On Fedora, what I did to add this arg to the kernel boot was running this:

```
sudo grubby --args=ibt=off --update-kernel /boot/vmlinuz-6.3.7-200.fc38.x86_64
```