# Guest os is not going to start on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

[image]

no progress in for starting VM.Can any one enlist the causes for it ?I have made ubuntu_64 VirtualBox with standard parameters. I am using ubuntu 15.04.Can anyone suggest why this is going to happen ?

Comment: Did you add the `ISO` file for it to boot from ?

Comment: Can you please explain what is ISO file and what is it for ? I have no idea for that . I am using VirtualBox first time.

Comment: OK, you need to download the `ubuntu.iso` installation media as you did when installing your own __Ubuntu 15.04__ that same file has to be added to the VM to have it boot like a normal Linux OS. __LIKE FROM [HERE](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)__

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that this problem is occurring.

Try installing the VirtualBox Kernel Module, if you haven't already. (Google it)

If that hasn't fixed your problem, try some of these webpages

[- https://askubuntu.com/questions/581301/virtualbox-stuck-on-starting-virtual-machine?rq=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581301/virtualbox-stuck-on-starting-virtual-machine?rq=1)

[- https://askubuntu.com/questions/675458/ubuntu-freezes-when-starting-virtualbox?rq=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675458/ubuntu-freezes-when-starting-virtualbox?rq=1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain (at least with a few words) what you think will work from the two links. And please explain more than 'Google it' about the VirtualBox Kernel Module.